# singleton variables in prolog

Tags: prolog

I was testing my new version of SWI prolog and keep coming across the error :**singleton variable**.

Example:

```
member(X,[X|T]).

member(X,[X|T]) :- member(X,T).
```

finds the member of a list such as :

```
member(yolands,[yolanda,tim])

X = yes
```

but instead I get a **singleton variables** error for X and T

if I do the following:

```
member(X,[X|_]).
member(X,[_|T]) :- member(X,T).
```

It works but looks ugly!

Can anyone explain why single variables ar enot allowed and if this ANSI standard?

Comment: In many systems you can write _T to avoid a singleton warning.

Comment: the warning for singleton happens also in your first test relatively to line 1

Answer (score 15):

Singleton variables are *useless* in Prolog, and are easily introduced by editing typos.

The *warning* is welcome to me, as it allows to easily spot such frequent cause of error.

Being a warning, you *can* run code containing singletons, but any value these eventually will assume will be lost.

I don't think that *ISO* standard (never heard about *ANSI*) forbids such variables.

You could rewrite your example in this way

```
member(X, [Y|T]) :- X = Y ; member(X, T).
```

and then forget about the singleton.

Comment: 2002-07-12, ANSI approved IS 13211-1.

Answer (score 12):

You have a bug here:

```
member(X,[X|T]) :- member(X,T).
```

What you're **actually** saying (as opposed to what you think you're saying) is that `member/2` holds if X is at the head of the list **and** present in the tail of the list. This predicate will only ever be true for the first N copies of the same thing at the beginning of a list, so it's a very strange thing to say!

```
?- member(X, [a,a,c]).
X = a ;
X = a ;
false.

?- member(X, [b,a,a]).
X = b ;
false.
```

Now, you could correct the bug and still have a singleton warning by doing something like this:

```
member(X, [Y|T]) :- member(X, T).
```

But this is neither as good as the conventional definition with two heads or @CapelliC's version (+1) with an explicit OR. I think you should wait until you understand Prolog a little better before putting much stock in your sense of Prolog code aesthetics. If you stick with it for a while you'll come to appreciate this warning as well as the use of anonymous variables.

What makes singleton variables useless in Prolog is that they're named but nothing is known about them and they have no effect on the rest of the computation. The underscore highlights that absolutely anything could go in there without affecting the meaning. What makes

```
member(X, [X|T]).
```

true is that the X is position 1 is the same as the X at the head of the list in position 2. Lists must either be empty or have a head and a tail, but what's in the tail is not relevant here, what matters is that X is also the head. The T could be the rest of the list, or it could be an improper list, or it could be a breadbox or lightning or the smell of the air on a spring day. It has no bearing on the truth of `member(X, [X|T])`.

The singleton warning tells you "you've reserved a name for something here, but you never call anything by that name." The first thing I do when I get this message and it isn't an obvious typo is replace the name with _ and see if my code still makes sense. If it doesn't, I have a logic error. If it does, it was probably unnecessary.

Comment: nice catch (+1): actually the bug was in the clause *without* singleton!

Comment: What do you meant with "CapelliC's version (+1) with an explicit OR": where is that OR in his clause?

Comment: @Bento the `;` is an explicit OR in Prolog.

Comment: I imagined that (infact "," is AND), but looking at the site LearnPrologNow some minutes ago (I'm litterally new to the Prolog language practice, but at least I know the theory) I have found no specifications for ";" syntax so I thought Capelli had an oversight. Now I know it was not the case :-) (incidentally I have found your answer very very useful for a problem I posed here in Edit2: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32942127/sorting-program-for-swi-prolog)

Comment: just a little question: which is the theoretic counterpart of that OR? Is that a bipartition of the ";" clause mantaining the same head and distributing the two atoms ?

Comment: I think however it is not equivalent from a logical point of view (the single clause does not implies the two clauses)

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about. There is an operational difference that makes the literal `;` more desirable: it eliminates an unnecessary choice point. If that's what you're talking about then yes, but I think logically (in contrast to Prolog's operational semantics) it is the same. Unfortunately, we do have to make choices when we decide to execute code on an actual machine though. :)

Comment: okay, I think (not quite sure..) you have hit the mark.. infact two clauses are less desirable than one

Answer (score 9):

You can read about it on the official page of [SWI-Prolog FAQ](http://www.swi-prolog.org/FAQ/SingletonVar.html)

The most common cases this warning appears are:

1. Spelling mistakes in variables
2. Forget to use/bind a variable

SWI suggest some ways to ignore it:

1. Use anonymous variable named _ for this purpose.
2. Use your variable starting with _ (like `_T`, `_X`), to avoid warning and document what you ignore.
3. If you are aware of what you are doing, you can use `:- style_check(-singleton).` and all warnings should go away.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example from Learn Prolog Now! (p 31). It produced the error message 'Singleton variables:...'

```
vertical(line(point(X,Y),point(X,Z))). 
horizontal(line(point(X,Y),point(Z,Y))).
```

Replacing [Y,Z] in vertical/1 and [X,Z] in horizontal/1 with anonymous variable _ got rid of the error message.

```
vertical(line(point(X,_),point(X,_))).
horizontal(line(point(_,Y),point(_,Y))).
```

Thank you everyone.