# GNU Prolog: member in list?

Tags: prolog, gnu-prolog

I'm using some code from the Art of Prolog.  This example is causing an error in GNU Prolog.

```
mem(X,[X|Xs]).
user:2: warning: singleton variables [Xs] for mem/2
mem(X,[Y|Ys]) :- mem(X,Ys).
user:3: warning: singleton variables [Y] for mem/2
```

Now I test a query, with negative results:

```
| ?- mem(g, [a, g, e]).
uncaught exception: error(existence_error(procedure,mem/2),top_level/0)
```

The example from the book:

[image]

It appears a singleton is a variable that is used only once in the expression.  To fix the warning:

```
mem(X, [X|_]).
mem(X, [_|Ys]) :- mem(X, Ys).


| ?- mem(b, [a, b, c]).
true

| ?- mem(d, [a, b, c]).

no
```

Why does the second expression not return false?  Also, why the differences from the Art of Prolog and GNU Prolog?  Did something change in the standard?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15416220/singleton-variables-in-prolog

Comment: That example has a bug in the code.  I eliminated the singleton error, but still get unexpected results.  I was expecting false in the last example.  Also, did the standards change since publication of this book?

Comment: "No" is the "False" you expect. There is not such a thing as a _standard_ Prolog. All implementations differ slightly here and there, and adhere to a published standard to some degree (some are very close to the standard and others do differently on purpose).

Comment: false and no can be considered equivalent. In SWI prolog, for example, you get false, but other prolog systems may adopt different conventions